# Accessing single elements in multi dimensional arrays using a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, element

I am trying to test whether an individual element inside an array of arrays matches up with a current vareiable using a for loop. I am ok with using a multi dimensional array or an array of objects to solve the issue as seen below:

```
const compassArray = [

  ["north", "top"],

  ["south", "bottom"],

  ["east", "right"],

  ["west", "left"],

];

const compassArray1 = [
  { direction: "north", message: "top" },

  { direction: "south", message: "bottom" },

  { direction: "east", message: "right" },

  { direction: "west", message: "left" },

];
```

However while accessing these individual elements in either case is easy doing so inside a for loop gives me an undefined result.

```
const rightTurn = () => {

  for (let i = compassArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (facing === compassArray[i][0]) {

      if (facing !== compassArray[compassArray.length][0]) {

        facing = compassArray[i + 1][0];

      } else {

        facing = compassArray[0][0];

      }
    }
  }
};
```

what is a reliable way of checking it "facing" is equal to element [0] in the compassArray? Other solutions not involving a for loop are also welcome as are other code critiques.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array `find` method with  `indexOf` or `includes` method.

Example:

```js
const compassArray = [
    ["north", "top"],
    ["south", "bottom"],
    ["east", "right"],
    ["west", "left"],
];

function findValue(str) {
    return compassArray.find(item => item.indexOf(str));
}


console.log(findValue("top"));
```